# Is it possible to create a Dockable Dialog with a GIMP plugin?

Tags: c, plugins, gimp

I've been working on a plugin for GIMP, written in C. It basically has a few inputs and a few buttons to trigger actions on the layers. All the functionality is doable through a plugin. And I can create dialog window for the input and buttons.

My question is: Is it possible to make this dialog dockable? It is basically a small row of 5 buttons and a couple inputs that I'd like to dock just below the layer's section.

Finding documentation on C plugins for GIMP hasn't been super easy but I did find there is a GimpDockable object in the API docs: https://developer.gimp.org/api/2.0/app/app-gimpdockable.html I cannot find it in any of the header files though. So I'm thinking maybe it is only available to people hacking on the actual application, not plugins.

I also found: [Creating GIMP interface plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36980514/creating-gimp-interface-plugins) but it seems to be asking for deeper integration into GIMP and is about Python. Not totally sure but I thought I read C plugins have more capability than Python (or Scheme.)

Any help would be appreciated. Not sure I want to go as far as building GIMP just to make my plugin dockable. But it'd be nice to know if that is the only way to achieve it so I can decide to just keep it as an 'always on top' window, menu items, or go ahead and try to figure out how to build the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plug-ins are executed as separate processes so their UI cannot be integrated in the main UI.

Comment: I was a little afraid of that. So there is no way at all for a plugin to talk to the main UI? No workarounds. Maybe pulling the GIMP code and linking it somehow to achieve it... though I guess if I'm going to go that far I may as well go all the way and just build the custom version of GIMP... either way, thanks for answering. I'll go ahead and accept the answer.

Comment: AFAIK it is a design decision to not allow the plug-ins to alter the UI.

Comment: Maybe I can find a way to psuedo-dock it by forcing its position to a specific spot of the parent window and making the window decorations toggle-able on/off or something like that. Guess I need to learn more about the gdk/gtk ui stuff... Thanks again!